# Find coefficient of $t^k$ in $\int_0^{2\pi}H_n(t\cos\phi+(1-t^2)^{1/2}\sin\phi)H_m(r\cos\phi)d\phi$, where $H_n$ is $n$th Hermite polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, special-functions, spherical-coordinates, hermite-polynomials

Let $n,m \ge 0$ be integers, $t \in [-1,1]$ and $r \in [0,1]$, and define
$$
s_{n,m}(t) := \int_0^{2\pi}H_n(rt\cos\phi+r(1-t^2)^{1/2}\sin\phi)H_m(r\cos\phi) d\phi,
$$
where $H_n$ is the $n$th Hermite polynomial.
Note that $s_{n,m}(t)$ is a polynomial in $t$.

> **Question.** *For any integer $k \in \{0,1,2,3\}$, what is the coefficient  $s_{n,m}[t^k]$ of $t^k$ in $s_{n,m}(t)$ ?*

### Observations

By basic properties of polynomials, we have the formula
$$
s_{n,m}(t)[t^k] = D^k s_{n,m}(t)\mid_{t=0},
$$
where $D$ is the differential operator $d/dt$.

Thus, one computes $s_{n,m}(t)[t^k] = \int_0^{2\pi}F_{n,k}(\phi)H_m(r\cos\phi) d\phi$, where

- $F_{n,0}(\phi) = H_n(r\sin\phi)$
- $F_{n,1}(\phi) = r\cos\phi H_n(r\sin\phi)$
- $F_{n,2}(\phi) = 4n(n-1)r^2\cos^2\phi H_{n-2}(r\sin\phi)-2nr\sin\phi H_{n-1}(r\sin\phi)$
- ...

(with the convention that $H_k(z) \equiv 0$ if $k < 0$)

Thus, the issue is reduced to being able to compute integrals of the form

$$
I = \int_0^{2\pi} \sin^N\phi H_n(r\sin\phi)\cos^M\phi H_m(r\cos\phi)d\phi.
$$

Comment: Looks to me like you just need to expand $H_n(rt\cos\phi+r(1-t^2)^{1/2}\sin\phi)$ using the definition of Hermite polynomial and try to collect terms, at least that's what I'd try first. Probably end up with sum infinite sum expressions due to the $(1-t^2)^{1/2}$ term, but then they might have closed forms.

Comment: Yep, I tried $H_n(x) = n!\sum_{k=0}^{n/2}(\ldots)$ but it doesn't lead to anything useful / simple.

Comment: However, that idea is potentially helpful in evaluating the integrals $I$ (defined at the end of the post).